# Kill a framework in Mesos

Tags: mesos

I have a Mesos cluster and was running a Spark shell connected to it.  I shut down the client, but Mesos still believes the framework should be active.

I am trying to have Mesos drop the framework by using DELETE with curl
(https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-1390)

but I am getting no response from the server.  Also, I am not sure how exactly to connect to the master: I have a multi-master setup managed by ZooKeeper, and I was trying to connect just to the active master:

```
curl -X DELETE http://<active master url>:5050/framworks/<framework id>
```

Can anyone verify if the above is the correct request?
I am using mesos-0.20.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though that JIRA issue mentions DELETE (in comments) it's not how framework shutdown is implemented. You need to do a POST request to /shutdown endpoint.

Examples: https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/master/src/tests/teardown_tests.cpp

Regarding why the spark framework is not removed after you shutdown the client, I'm guessing it is because spark uses a high failover timeout? Nonetheless, I'm surprised that Mesos UI shows it as active instead of inactive.

Comment: Note that /shutdown has been deprecated in favor of /teardown

Answer (score 21):

There is a restfull option calling by post the url `http://your_mesos:5050/master/teardown` passing frameworkId parameter

```
curl -d@/tmp/post.txt -X POST http://your_mesos:5050/master/teardown
```

/tmp/post.txt is a file with the follow content:

```
frameworkId=23423-23423-234234-234234
```

I know is late but for future askers

EDIT: The endpoint is now called `teardown`.
Example (thanks @Jeff): `curl -X POST http://your_mesos:5050/master/teardown -d 'frameworkId=23423-23423-234234-234234'`

Comment: even easier is `curl -XPOST http://your_mesos:5050/master/shutdown -d 'frameworkId=your_framework_id'`

Comment: 'shutdown' didn't work for me. I had to use 'teardown' instead.

Answer (score 18):

Just to keep this up to date: The master endpoint was renamed to teardown i.e. http://localhost:5050/master/teardown is the new way to go.

TEARDOWN Request (JSON):

```
POST /master/teardown HTTP/1.1
Host: masterhost:5050
Content-Type: application/json
frameworkId=12220-3440-12532-2345
```

TEARDOWN Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Ok
```

Comment: so should I write the suggested curl command as : curl -d@/tmp/post.txt -X POST http://localhost:5050/master/teardown ?

Comment: @CruncherBigData yes, just replace `shutdown` with `teardown`. By the way, you can write `-d 'frameworkId=#'` instead of using file.

Comment: `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d 'frameworkId=547d0f00-b084-4b5c-bd1b-5ea6c5f8abd1-0000' -v -L http://localhost:5050/teardown` (/master/teardown and /teardown are the same thing)

Answer (score 5):

Riffing on @montells work, a one-liner would be

```
echo "frameworkId= 23423-23423-234234-234234" | curl -d@- -X POST http://localhost:5050/master/shutdown
```

Comment: Anyone know where the API is documented? I haven't found it yet. Also, with Mesos 0.23+, /master/teardown is the new path as /master/shutdown is being deprecated. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-2697

Comment: http api can be tracked via this ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-2289

Comment: Be careful of having a space in front of the ID. The space has caused me problems in the past

Answer (score 3):

Add this in your .bashrc:

```
#Mesos
killtask(){ curl -XPOST http://mesos_url:5050/master/teardown -d 'frameworkId='$@''; } ;
```

Sample usage:

```
killtask 123
```

Comment: Bigups.. this answer is the best